# Minkowski functional of C satisfies triang. ineq. iff C convex

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I'm trying to prove that given a subset $C \subseteq  (X, \parallel \cdot \parallel )$ normed vector space, $0 \in C$, and its Minkowski functional $p_C$, then it holds

$C$ convex iff $p_C$ satisties the triangle inequality , $p_C(x+y) \leq p_C(x) + p_C(y)$.

I have "$ \Rightarrow$".

"$ \Leftarrow$" holds if I prove that $C= \{ x \in X : p_C(x) \leq 1 \}$ (and I need to prove this equality!). "$\subseteq$" is trivial, but I don't know how to prove "$\supseteq$". All bibliography I have read proves this equalily knowing that $C$ is convex, but I can only use that $p_C$ satisties the triangle inequality.

**So, ¿how to prove that if $x \in X$ verifies $p_C(x) \leq 1$ then $x \in C$?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't. What you can show is that $\{ x : p_C(x) < 1\} \subseteq C \subseteq \{ x : p_C(x) \leqslant 1\}$, under the hypothesis that $C$ is star-shaped with respect to $0$. If for example $C$ is an open convex neighbourhood of $0$, then $C = \{ x : p_C(x) < 1\}$.

Comment: The Minkowski functional satisfies the triangle inequality if $C$ is centered at 0 and it is convex.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that $0 \in C$. So, how to prove that if $p_C$ satisties the triangle inequality , $p_C(x+y) \leq p_C(x) + p_C(y)$, then $C$ is convex? The only way I realise if through that equality. @DanielFischer

Comment: If you merely assume $0 \in C$, and not that $C$ is star-shaped with respect to $0$, what is the precise definition of the Minkowski functional you're working with?

Comment: Given $A \subset X$ with $0 \in A$, $p_A(x) := \inf \{\sigma > 0 : x \in \sigma A \}$. I suppose that I must assume that $A$ is absorbing. @DanielFischer

Comment: Even if we assume the set to be absorbing (it doesn't help that there are several nonequivalent definitions of the term around; let's take [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_set)), that isn't sufficient. Consider $C = \{ x\in X : \lVert x\rVert < 1/2 \lor \lVert x\rVert = 1\}$. Then $p_C(x) = \lVert x\rVert$, so the triangle inequality holds, but [unless $X = \{0\}$] $C$ is not convex.

Comment: It's really only useful to consider the Minkowski functional for sets that are star-shaped with respect to $0$, otherwise you have to take too many oddities into account. If we assume that $C$ is star-shaped, then we have $A := \{ x : p_C(x) < 1\} \subseteq C \subseteq B := \{ x : p_C(x) \leqslant 1\}$. If $p_C$ satisfies the triangle inequality, $A$ and $B$ are convex. But without further restrictions, it does not follow that $C$ itself is convex. Take for example $C = [-1,1] \times [-1,1] \setminus \{(1,0)\}$. That's not convex, but its Minkowski functional is the maximum norm on the plane.

Comment: How do you prove the forward direction? I can't seem to get anywhere